# JS DOM NODES: Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom, nodes, innerhtml

With the help of a loop, I want to add an element into my list items.

Thanks a bunch for any advice!

Comment: Are you adding a single element? What do you need the loop for? And where are you trying to add them / it?

Comment: I want to add it to every list item. This is just to practice using loops!

Comment: Into it how? What is the final code look like?

Comment: If `items` is your NodeList of `<li>` elements, then `items[i]` would refer to the specific `<li>` at that index.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little hard to tell the context of your problem, but I think using a for...of loop would better meet your needs, as it works with each item of the list individually.

Try this:

```
let item = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (let i of item){
    i.innerHTML = `${i.innerText} <span class="credits">100 credits</span>`;
}
```

If you need something that specifically uses an index loop, try this:

```
let item = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++){
    item[i].innerHTML = `${item[i].innerText} <span class="credits">100 credits</span>`;
}
```